# Unknown Error on opening Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When i try open Visual Studio, I immediately receive an error message. The message only tell me to open a xml file to receive more informations.

The directory of the xml file is `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_ae456ee1\ActivityLog.xml`

[image: Content of the xml file.]

I already tried some possible solutions, like delete the privateregistry.bin file, on this directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_ae456ee1. But when I delete this file and try open Visual Studio, instead of receive the error immediately, the logo of Visual Studio appears, then the error message appears and the privateregistry.bin file is re-created.

This problem first happened in the Visual Studio 2017 Community. I reinstalled this version and downloaded Visual Studio Professional, but the error continues.

Comment: have you tried running as admin? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac06667a-56e6-4f95-9926-413a2d949f76/vs-2017-package-management-initialization-failed?forum=vssetup

Comment: I tried, but the error continues.

Comment: run VS2017 installer and repair Visual Studio

Comment: check your permissions on AppData for your user profile.

Comment: I repaired Visual Studio, and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: @LuizHenrique i posted a answer so people can see what you did, mark as answered if its correct.

Answer (score 0):

My exact issue was for an Unreal Engine 4 solution. The problem was the the intermediate folder was moved, and a new one re-generated. Instead of having to re-generate project files (from the .uproject), I simply deleted the auto-generated intermediate folder and replaced with the moved/old version (which included the build files from an initial project generation from the .uproject).

It is at least better to try a solution other than repairing the install, as that will delete external plugins and preferences...

Answer (score -1):

**Repair Visual Studio 2017**

1. Sometimes your Visual Studio installation becomes damaged or corrupted. A repair can fix this.

   Find the Visual Studio Installer on your computer.

   For example, on a computer running Windows 10 Anniversary Update or later, select Start, 
   and then scroll to the letter V, where it's listed as Visual Studio Installer.

> Note
>
> On some computers, the Visual Studio Installer might be listed under
>   the letter "M" as the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer.
>
> Alternatively, you can find the Visual Studio Installer in the
>   following location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe`

2. Click or tap to start the installer, then select More, and then select Repair.